# Can't find myself in the query database

Tags: support, data-explorer

I was trying to find a question that I'd commented on on math.stackexchange.com (This should be MUCH easier than it is!!).

I found the query frontend at https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/....

I'm user4894.

The query

```
select id,DisplayName from Users where len(DisplayName)=8 and 
DisplayName like 'user%'
order by DisplayName
```

returns user4891 and user4895 one after the other, without user4894 in the middle. Here is a screencap of the relevant part of the results:

[image]

What is happening? Numerous other query attempts returned similar results, the query behaves correctly but does not find me.

Comment: You're running your query on the [so] database, not [math.se]'s database. http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/new should be the right link.

Comment: You are not a number, you are a free man!  (ahem, sorry..)

Comment: @hichris123 That's an answer, not a comment ;)

Answer (score 3):

You're running your query on the [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) database, not [Mathematics's](https://math.stackexchange.com/) database. https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/new should be the right link.

[hichris123](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/237685/hichris123) comment answered the question...